# Qt - undefined reference to QJsonValue::toString

Tags: qt, qjson

I'm trying to build a sample project using Qt 5.7 over Linux. Previously, the same project have been built with Qt 5.4.2 without issues. When I try with Qt 5.7, I get the followings errors:

```
undefined reference to `QJsonValue::toString() const'
```

I have tried installing Qt5.7 with **Qt Maintenance Tool** and also download from Qt official site and install it using .run file. When I run a locate to qjsonvalue I get the followings results:

```
$ locate qjsonvalue
/opt/Qt/5.4/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/qjsonvalue.h
/opt/Qt/5.4/Src/qtbase/src/corelib/json/qjsonvalue.cpp
/opt/Qt/5.4/Src/qtbase/src/corelib/json/qjsonvalue.h
/opt/Qt/5.4/android_armv7/include/QtCore/qjsonvalue.h
/opt/Qt/5.4/android_x86/include/QtCore/qjsonvalue.h
/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qjsonvalue.h
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qjsonvalue.h
/usr/share/doc/qt5/qtcore/qjsonvalue-members.html
/usr/share/doc/qt5/qtcore/qjsonvalue.html
```

According with the previous results, seems that I need to install something becuase qjsonvalue.h/cpp is not in my Qt5.7 core. Any ideas about how to solve it? Need to install anything else? As note, when I start Qt Maintenance Tool I get an alert message that says the following:

```
Your installation seems to be corrupted. Please consider re-installing from scratch.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this comming here via google. I had the same issue.

The API changed from a default argument
[`QString QJsonValue::toString(const QString & defaultValue = QString()) const`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qjsonvalue.html#toString)
to [two overloads](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#toString).
`QString QJsonValue::toString() const`
`QString QJsonValue::toString(const QString &defaultValue) const`

You should build with the headers of the oldest version you want to support. But if you just need this one error fixed you can just change the call from

```
QJsonValue someval;
QString str = someval.toString();
```

to

```
QString str = someval.toString(QString());
```

But you will probably get some other linker error in the wake of fixing this one.